# How to preserve separation between <p> tags using JSoup?

Tags: java, html, parsing, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to write a program to get the lyrics of a song.  This is my first time using website parsing, I am using JSoup.  I wrote a method that would give me the lyrics, but only as one big, unformatted string.

The website with the lyrics is: http://www.metrolyrics.com/lights-out-words-gone-lyrics-bombay-bicycle-club.html

They separate the verses with p tags, and br tags and I'm not sure how to preserve the separation between them.

This is what I have right now:

```
public static String getLyrics(String url) throws Exception
{
    int i = 0;
    String lyrics = "";
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements lines = document.select("p.verse");
    String [] verses = new String[lines.size()];
    for(Element el : lines)
        verses[i++] = el.text();
    for(String verse : verses)
        lyrics = lyrics + verse + "\n";
    return lyrics;
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static String getLyrics(String url) throws Exception {
    int i = 0;
    StringBuilder lyrics = new StringBuilder();
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements lines = document.select("p.verse");
    String [] verses = new String[lines.size()];
    for(Element el : lines)
        verses[i++] = el.html();        

    for(String verse : verses)
        lyrics.append(verse + System.getProperty("line.separator") + System.getProperty("line.separator"));

    return lyrics.toString().replaceAll("<br>\\s+", System.getProperty("line.separator")).trim();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much, I just changed "<br>\\s+" to "<br />" and It works exactly as it should in my program.  one thing I was wondering about though is if System.getProperty("line.separator") is the same function as \n?

Comment: Yes it is. It is better though, since it's portable. Please mark the answer, so the thread can be closed.